# How do I select the text and replace it using regex via jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I've looked at a lot of stack posts and Google results but I can't quite find my answer... I have this snippet of text.

`<p>Lorem JohnJones@xyz.com , consectetur adipisicing elit. Eos, doloribus, dolorem iusto blanditiis unde eius illum consequuntur neque dicta incidunt ullam ea hic porro optio ratione repellat</p>`

I'm trying to target the email addresses and then underline them. It's important that the body is selected rather than the `<p>` tag. I've made an expression that I know works since I made it via [RegexPlanet](http://www.regexplanet.com/).

So far, I have this:

```
var result = $("body").text();
var newResult =result.replace("\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b", "REPLACED");
console.log(newResult);
```

But it doesn't seem to work... If you go to this [Here](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRi-iZYWDA/index.html) and then click JavaScript, you will see the result of `input.replace()`. That is essentially what I'm after but I'd also like to be able to use jQuery's `.css()` function.

How can I do this?

Comment: how does you need to use `.css` come into play?

Comment: When you read the text and change it, it does not automatically map back to the element. You need to set the HTML back. And by using `text()` you will strip all HTML from the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could make it work by using html() instead of text(), changing the regex and reassigning the result to body:

```
var result = $("body").html();
var newResult = result.replace(/\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b/g, "REPLACED");
$("body").html(newResult);
```

Instead of using "REPLACED" in the replace function you could use a function to surround the email within a span like this:

```
var newResult = result.replace(/\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b/g,
    function (x) { return '<span class="underlined">' + x  + '</span>';});
```

Comment: How could I edit my expression to do what it does right now but also make sure the domain of the email is always `@xyz.com` for instance? If the email address didn't contain `@xyz.com` then it would simply ignore it?

Comment: /\b[\w\.-]+@xyz.com\b/g

Answer (score 0):

Try this, without quotes on the regex:

```
var result = $("body").html();
var newResult = result.replace(/\b[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+\.\w{2,4}\b/ig, "REPLACED");
console.log(newResult);
//Lorem REPLACED , consectetur adipisicing elit.....
```

---

**Notes:**

Use `$("body").html();` instead of `$("body").text();` in order to keep the `html` tags.
Your regex is weak to match emails, try to improve it.

---

Demo:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/epBvxG

Comment: How could I edit my expression to do what it does right now but also make sure the domain of the email is always `@xyz.com` for instance? If the email address didn't contain `@xyz.com` then it would simply ignore it?